# How to push website links from phone to chrome/other browser?

Tags: applications, browser

I can't seem to find an app for this. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: And I can't seem to understand what exactly you are looking for. Could you please update your question with an example scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You could click the overflow button (menu) and choose to share the page. Then using an app like Evernote or Catch, sync the data to your desktop PC.

Alternatively, if you use Chrome as your desktop browser - use [Phone 2 Google Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lg.valle.phone2chrome) which uses the above concept. Also, take a look at [Android2Cloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suchagit.android2cloud) which has similar functionality.